# Adding separate values as an array to a combobox

Tags: powershell, foreach, combobox

My goal is to obtain a list of printers from my print server by name and add them as separate items in a combobox for a user to select. This is what I have come up with, but it isn't working:

```
$Hospital        = Get-Printer -ComputerName servername | where{$_.Name -like “*Name*”} | format-list name

$ComboBox_Location.Add_Click{

    switch ($ComboBox_Location.SelectedItem){
    "Hospital"{
        $ComboBox_Printer.Clear();
            foreach($Name in $Hospital){
            $ComboBox_Printer.Items.Add($Name.Name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I figure it has something to do with "foreach", but I can't quite understand it. I have seen things like;

```
foreach($Name in $Names)
```

and I don't understand how you can search within a variable by subtracting one letter?? I don't know. There are more than 40 printers in this list and I want each of them to pull up as a separate item in this combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you've put `| format-list` on the end of the `$Hospital = ..` line. This is changing the object type to format objects, which aren't useful for anything other than display.

Remove the `| format-list` and it looks to me like your code should otherwise work.

You're using `ForEach` correctly. The 'magic' is just that whatever variable you decide to use gets populated on each iteration of the loop. So if you have a collection of `$Names`, then `ForEach ($Name in $Names) { .. }` will go through the `$Names` collection and one at a time put each object it contains in $Name, which you can then use inside the curly braces to reference / manipulate / output as you require. `$Name` can therefore be called whatever you like, so long as you use it consistently inside the `ForEach`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So, my code now looks like this;
$Hospital        = Get-Printer -ComputerName servername | where{$_.Name -like “*Name*”}

$ComboBox_Location.Add_Click{

    switch ($ComboBox_Location.SelectedItem){
    "Hospital"{
        $ComboBox_Printer.Clear();
            foreach($Name in $Names){
            $ComboBox_Printer.Items.Add($Name.Name)

It still isnt working. I dont think iit is pulling the Names of these printers like I want it to.

What am I missing/not quite getting?

Comment: Run the `$Hospital` line on its own and then check to see if it has the contents you are expecting. E.g that it is a collection of objects with a `name` property.

Comment: $Hospital brings up all their information, including name, server, port, etc. So, I did foreach($Name in $Hospital){$ComboBox_Printer.Items.Add($Name)} and it does not add any items when clicked on. Do I need to set $Name to retrieve the printer names? Or how does that work?

Comment: No you’re referencing it in the .add and it gets populated by the foreach. I would guess the add method is not working in the combo box. You could further just verify that in your foreach each printer name is listed by just outputting them instead of doing the add.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to put quotes around $Name after the .add. Forgot about that. But now, with the list popping up, it doesn't bring up just the name. It lists the entire information; "MSFT_Printer (Name = "PrinterName", ComputerName = "server", DeviceType = 0, Type = 0)"

Comment: Are you still doing $name.name?

Comment: Yes. It brings up the entire configuration of the listed printers

Comment: Oh try this: $($Name.name). You’re accessing a property within a string so it needs to wrapped in a sub expression. You need to ensure you’re using double quotes too.